# If it is Arithmetic Progression then find the value of s?

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

The value of s = [image]
I started this question by making an A.P as the common difference is same and got the answer that I need number of terms to proceed further but my valie for number of terms is coming in fraction that is not possible i tried many times but end up with the same value so I can't proceed further as I don't know the value of n to put in the sum of Arithmetic Progression series?

Comment: Why would you think this was an arithmetic progression?

Comment: As the common difference is same and it is the question of chapter A.P

Comment: The common difference is the same?  Are you sure?  What value are you getting for the common difference?

Comment: The terms of this series are of the form $\frac1{(5k+2)(5(k+1)+2))}$ for $k\geq0$. Decompose this fraction by partial fraction decomposition to get a telescoping series.

Comment: In case lulu's comments were not blatant enough, this is *not* an arithmetic progression.  An arithmetic progression is one of the form $a+nk$ where $a$ is the first term, $n$ is the index, and $k$ is the common difference between terms.  There is not a common difference here.  For instance the difference between the first two is $\frac{1}{84}-\frac{1}{14}=-\frac{5}{84}$ while the difference between the second two is $\frac{1}{204}-\frac{1}{84}=-\frac{5}{714}$, a different number.  There is not a common factor here either so it is also not geometric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

The general term is $$\frac{1}{(5r-3)(5r+2)}$$

We use partial fraction decomposition, so:

$$\frac{1}{(5r-3)(5r+2)}=\frac{A}{5r-3}+\frac{B}{5r+2}$$

Can you find $A$ and $B$? (Hint 2:  $A+B=0$)

Because $A+B=0$, can you see that between the decomposition of $$\frac{1}{(5r-3)(5r+2)}$$ and $$\frac{1}{(5(r+1)-3)(5(r+1)+2)}=\frac{1}{(5r+2)(5r+7)}$$

some terms are cancelled? Figure out which ones will not be cancelled and sum them.

This method is known as [telescoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)